# Pattern lookup within a string in R using regular expression matching

Tags: r, regex

I am  trying to pick patterns within a specific string and their respective location. I have explained below with an example:

```
String = "Web_797-Web_797-Web_797-Web_797-PCP_IM_PAR-Pharm_1-Pharm_1-
Web_797-PCP_IM_PAR-Prior_OP-Web_797-Prior_OP-Event_0-"

pattern = "Web_797-*Web_797" (Web_797 followed by Web_797 with anything in between)
```

I used the following function:

```
 str_locate_all(String,pattern)[[1]]
```

I am getting the following result:

```
      start end
[1,]     1  15
[2,]    17  31
```

which is what I need partially. However I the pattern is not able to pick the following combination (highlighted in black).

String = "Web_797-Web_797-Web_797-Web_797-PCP_IM_PAR-Pharm_1-Pharm_1-
    **Web_797-PCP_IM_PAR-Prior_OP-Web_797**-Prior_OP-Event_0-"

I would appreciate if anyone could help with this. I believe there is something wrong with the way I am defining the pattern but not able to fix it.

Comment: You need `pattern = "Web_797-.*?Web_797" `

Comment: Thanks, that works! You are an angel, sir!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your pattern   `pattern = "Web_797-*Web_797"`  is the `-*` part. That means zero or more dashes (-).   I believe what you wanted was a dash followed by any characters. So a first (incorrect) attempt would be 
`pattern = "Web_797-.*Web_797"`  Where the . means "any character".  But that is not quite right. You only want to collect characters until the *next* time you see Web_797, not all the way until the last time you see Web_797.  By default,  the matches are "greedy" taking the biggest possible match. If we use 
`pattern = "Web_797-.*?Web_797"`   the ? turns off greedy matching so that it only matches to the next Web_797.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I get really confused with the regular expressions in R. This helps!